# How to translate OnMouse events to Touch phases for Android?

Tags: android, button, unity-game-engine, touch, unityscript

I'm stuck to a rather simple solution, with my script translated run in Android with Unity3d. I'm having a gameObject "Cube" and a js script attached for rotation.

Also I' m having a script "ClickButton.js" attached to a GUI.Texture. Everything works o.k. in Unity Player, but I want to translate this script to be used by touches in Android devices. Problem is I can't do it, although I have read the Unity documentation.

Here is the code snippet:

```
//This script is attached on a GUI.Texture acting as a button

var normalTexture : Texture2D;
var hoverTexture : Texture2D;

function Update(){
    for (var i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; ++i) {
        if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            var rotate = Input.GetTouch(i);
            rotate == doRotate();
        }
    }
}

function OnMouseEnter(){
    guiTexture.texture = hoverTexture;
}

function OnMouseExit(){
    guiTexture.texture = normalTexture;
}

function OnMouseDown(){  
    var runScriptRotate : GameObject[] = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Marker");    
    for(var doRotation : GameObject in runScriptRotate){    
        var scriptRT : doRotate = doRotation.GetComponent(doRotate);    
        if(scriptRT){
            // access the function "doRotation" on a script named "doRotate" on     gameObject "Cube"
            doRotate.doRotation();
        }    
    }      
}
```

Can somebody, be kind enough to edit this code script, so to make it work on Android by touching? Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just copy the contents of `OnMouseDown()`? Basically touch is the same as mouse down on android devices, isn't it?

```
if(Input.touchCount > 0){
    if(Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began){
        var runScriptRotate : GameObject[] = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Marker");    
        for(var doRotation : GameObject in runScriptRotate){    
            var scriptRT : doRotate = doRotation.GetComponent(doRotate);    
            if(scriptRT){
                // access the function "doRotation" on a script named "doRotate" on gameObject "Cube"
                doRotate.doRotation();
            }    
        }     
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hi @JayKazama, thanks for your reply, but didn't work out. I get this error in compiler "Error BCE0019: 'getTouch' is not a member of 'UnityEngine.Input'". Any work around?

Comment: Ah sorry, it should be `GetTouch` with capital G, and also `.phase` not `.touchPhase`. I've editted my answer. Give it a try.